# ¿Cómo iterar cogiendo dos ficheros cada vez?

Tags: linux, bash, bucle-for, unix, shell-script

quiero desarrollar un script shell que llame a un programa que requiere dos archivos de entrada.
La cuestión está en que, no es solo una pareja la tiene que procesar, sino x numero de parejas que se encuentran en el mismo directorio.

En el directorio tengo por ejemplo:

- 1nt.fa
- 2aa.fa
- 2nt.fa
- 2aa.fa
- 3nt.fa
- 3aa.fa
- 4nt.fa
- 4aa.fa
- 5nt.fa
- 5aa.fa

la línea de comandos del programa es la siguiente:

```
xvfb-run ete3 build -a 1aa.fa -n 1nt.fa -o mix_types -w standard_fasttree --clearall --nt-switch-threshold 0.0
```

Y lo que intenté fue lo siguiente, pero no funcionó:

```
#!/bin/bash
aa='eteanalysis/*.aa.fa'
nt='eteanalysis/*.nt.fa'
for f in eteanalysis/; do
    xvfb-run ete3 build\
    -a $aa\
    -n $nt\
    -w standard_fasttree\
    --clearall\
    --nt-switch-threshold 0.0\
    -o mixed_types/${f%.fasta}.ete3
done
```

Alguna idea?...También lo he intentado con parallel pero tampoco me funciono

---

@fedorqui logre desarrollar algo con ayuda y funciona hasta cierto punto. Lo que no termina de funcionar es el iterador creo yo, ya que en las pruebas que hago con seis parejas, el script solo itera sobre dos, ¿a que se puede deber esto?..

```
#!/bin/bash
for aa in *.aa.fa; do
    nt=${aa%.aa.fa}.nt.fa
    b="${aa%.*}"
    if [[ ! -e $nt ]]; then
        echo "$nt not found skipping.." >&2
        continue;
    fi
    xvfb-run ete3 build\
    -a "$aa"\
    -n "$nt"\
    -w standard_fasttree\
    --clearall\
    --nt-switch-threshold 0.0\
    -o $b.ete3
done
```

Comment: sería bueno que simplificaras el problema, pues hay mucha información seguramente no relevante para la pregunta que complica su entendimiento. Dicho lo cual, si guardas `*` dentro de comillas simples, no se expandirá. Luego, ¿se supone que el directorio donde trabajas es "eteanalysis"? En tal caso, para iterar sobre esos ficheros deberías hacer `for f in eteanalysis/*`

Comment: Vas a tener que utilizar bucles probablemente. De manera que en cada iteración leas una pareja de ficheros, y ejecutes el comando para cada pareja. Lo digo porque en principio tu programa no está preparado para más de dos datos, verdad? Además, al expandir `*`, cuando quites las comillas simples, le estarás pasando todos los ficheros al programa, no de dos en dos.

Comment: Exacto, el programa no esta preparado para para mas de dos dato @Eequiis Vásquez  y precisamente quiero, que lea cada pareja de ficheros y ejecute el comando para cada pareja.

Comment: Pues como he comentado, tienes que utilizar bucles, listar los ficheros y ejecutar el programa para cada pareja de ficheros.

Answer (score 1):

Por lo que veo quieres iterar sobre la pareja de archivos `Nnt.fa` y `Naa.fa`, de manera que cada vez tengas acceso a un par de ellos.

Para ello, una posible solución es iterar sobre uno de los tipos de archivo y construir el nombre del otro a partir de este:

```
for f in *nt.fa
do
  aa="${f/nt/aa}"
  # cosas con "$f" y "$aa", el primero contiene "1nt.fa" y el segundo "1aa.fa"
done
```